# Inquiring about finding mentors in the drupal community

Tags: community-official-site

Recently, I've noticed that drupal.org has added [user profile fields](http://drupal.org/user/760600) for areas such as adding drupal ID's for attributing thanks to some mentors.

I was curious as to see if there currently is a means or process of seeking or finding a drupal mentor online or through drupal.org? I would ask people in person but i really don't know that many drupalers at the current moment.

Would the best place to look be the forums on Drupal.org? Or just persistent begging on IRC? I would eventually like to mentor others myself once i feel comfortable

Comment: Also found this link helpful: http://drupalofficehours.org/tasks?field_level_value=2&tid=All&field_priority_tid=All

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to Drupal! There are established core-office-hours for folks looking for mentorship (and looking to mentor); Your best best is to start there and outline your skill set. Someone will be more than happy to help. See http://drupal.org/core-office-hours - So you don't have to beg in IRC. Just show up at the appropriate time. :)